# Loop not triggering on structure array testing

Tags: c, for-loop, struct

I'm just starting to explore C, so i'll appreciate any code style advice.  However my specific problem is in understanding why my `else if` conditional is not getting triggered.  As you can see in the comments, I realize my `loop->word` seems like it never got initialized, but the second time through the `for loop` i'm thinking that atleast one word should be added?

Code:

```
 typedef struct node{
     char word[15];
     int count;
 } node;


 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int word_size = 500, dict_size=10;
     char words[word_size];

     // main prompt
     printf("Enter some words: ");
     fgets(words, word_size, stdin);

     // create a list of nodes, and iterator through array
     struct node dict[dict_size];
     struct node *head = dict;
     struct node *loop = dict;

     // pointer for tokenization, starts at [0] until delimiter
     char *pch;
     pch = strtok(words, " ");
     // TODO: dict[0] so that last is equal to 1, and can use that as max loop?

     // keep track of how many nodes have been updated
     int i, j, last = 0;

     while(pch != NULL){
         printf("pch == %s\n", pch); // this works

         for(i=0; i<dict_size; i++, loop++) {
             printf("inner = %d\n", i); // this works
             printf("loop->word == %s\n", loop->word); // realize i'm testing against nonsense?

             if(loop->word == pch){
             // loop through each dict element, looking for matching word
             // increment the value pointed to by loop->count
                 printf("%s was found in dict[%d], incrementing counter", loop->word, loop->count);
                 loop->count = loop->count + 1;
                 break;

             } else if(i == dict_size){
             // key doesn't exist so update the next struct
                 printf("adding %s, with count 1.\n", pch);
                 strcpy(dict[last].word, pch);
                 dict[last].count = 1;
                 last++;
             }
         }
         // lastly move token, and reset pointer @ head of the dictionary
         pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
         loop = head;
     }

     // set pointers to null?
     loop = NULL;
     head = NULL;
     printf("done");
```

Edit: sorry for the wall of code, not sure what's the minimal code needed for a c problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Inside a for loop where the condition is `i<dict_size` how do you expect it to be equal to `dict_size` if the only place where it is not incrememented in the body of the for loop.
- What you might want is that after the loop is over - check whether `i == dict_size` then you will be sure that it is not found. Here inside the for loop you are checking for `i ==  dict_size` which will be outside of it.
- Also `loop->word == pch` is comparing two pointers - but you want to compare two strings - which will be done using `strcmp`. So the structure of the code will be

  ```
  for(i = ..; i < dict_size ; ... ){
     if(strcmp(loop->word, pch) == 0){
        /*  found */
     }
     ...
  }
  if( i == dict_size){
     /* not found */
  }
  ```
- `fgets` return value should be checked to check the failure or success of the function call. This level error checking is important.

Comment: I had to reread that a few times, and then it hit me.  Thank you very much, can't believe I missed the increment range.  It's surprising how much I've never thought of these little things with Python.